# How to check gnome keyrings state with c code or python?

Tags: python, c, gnome, gnome-keyring-daemon

Currently using the command line gkey-lock/gkey-unlock with the flowing code to lock and unlock gnome default keyring, How can we implement `gnome_keyring_info_get_is_locked()` from `<gnome-keyring.h>` to check the locking state in c or python

***Lock Keyring - gkey-lock.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gnome-keyring.h>

int main() {
    GnomeKeyringResult lock_result = gnome_keyring_lock_all_sync();
    if (lock_result == GNOME_KEYRING_RESULT_OK) {
        printf("Successfully locked\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Error locking keyring: %d\n", lock_result);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

***Unlock Keyring - gkey-unlock.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gnome-keyring.h>

int main() {
    GnomeKeyringResult lock_result = gnome_keyring_unlock_sync(NULL,NULL);
    if (lock_result == GNOME_KEYRING_RESULT_OK) {
        printf("Successfully unlocked\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        printf("Error unlocking keyring: %d\n", lock_result);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gnome Keyring Command Line Tools (check/lock/unlock)**

Sources & Release : https://github.com/intika/gnome-keyring-tools

***Check Keyring - gkey-check.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gnome-keyring.h>

int main() {

  GnomeKeyringInfo *info;
  GnomeKeyringResult gkr;

  gkr = gnome_keyring_get_info_sync(NULL, &info);
  if (gkr != GNOME_KEYRING_RESULT_OK) {
    printf("error\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if (gnome_keyring_info_get_is_locked(info)) {
    printf("locked\n");
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    printf("unlocked\n");
    return -1;
  }
  gnome_keyring_info_free(info);

}
```

***Check With Python - gkey-check.py***

```
import gnomekeyring
print gnomekeyring.get_info_sync(gnomekeyring.get_default_keyring_sync()).get_is_locked()
```

***How to build***

```
cc gkey-check.c -o gkey-check -Wall -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -lgnome-keyring -lglib-2.0
```